# Expire variables after specific time in ruby

Tags: ruby, redis

I have a class with `array = [element1, element2, element3]`. I set expire for `element1 = 1s`, `element2 = 5s`, `element3 = 7s` at the same time. 
That means after 1s later the array will change to `[element2, element3]` 
5s later `[element3]`, 7s later will be empty array. How we can do this? 
It like the ways we set expire for Redis `expire key 30`, `ttl key`.

Comment: Yes, we do. It involves writing the code to check to see how much time has expired then assigning `nil` to them. I've never seen a reason to do what you're talking about in code. Instead I'd refuse to do something that requires use of those variables if the time has expired.

Comment: I have just edit the question for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in functionality for this in ruby, and there are many different data structures you could use to implement it, depending on the situation.

Here's a simplistic example:

```
class Ephemarray
  def initialize
    @array = []
  end

  def [] index
    return nil if @array[index].nil?
    return @array[index] = nil if (Time.now - @array[index][2] > @array[index][1])
    return @array[index][0]
  end

  def []= index, expiry, value
    @array[index] = [value, expiry, Time.now]
  end

end

e = Ephemarray.new
e[0, 4] = 'blah'
```

Of course, you could always solve this problem with `gem install redis` c;